# when i use Beautifulsoup to open a url，i meet a trouble:IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename

Tags: python-2.7

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup =bs(open('http://www.baidu.com'))
print soup.prettify()

thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems like you can't directly open the page.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "http://www.baidu.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = bs(page)
print soup.prettify()
```